# Show one property of an object with ng-options and select (not array)

Tags: angularjs

I would like to show only my `item.name` from my object and I don´t know how to do it.

Here is my pen and now the "name" and "age" properties are being shown.

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/beneivol/pen/woOOgg?editors=1010#0)

```
<body>
    <div ng-controller="Test">
      <select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="k.name as v for (k,v) in items">
      </select>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Please, insert your code in the question (avoid external sites). It helps who's reading, no matter if it's to help you or if searching for a similar problem.

Comment: I was trying to add my code in a plunker box but I could not. I´ll try again in my next question. Thank you Tom

Comment: Does [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41263934/4927984) solved your issue? :)

Answer (score 0):

`$scope.items` has to be an array, then you can loop over items in your `ng-options` like this:

### In your Angular controller

```
$scope.items = [
    {name: 'Michael', age: 29},
    {name: 'John', age: 29},
    {name: 'Ronald', age: 29}
];
```

### In your HTML

```
<select ng-model="selectedItem" ng-options="i.name for i in items"></select>
```

[**Forked your CodePen here.**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bBZZvr?editors=1010#0)